# How to call CustomDelegate functions Textfield takes it's new size

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

I want to create a custom `UITextfield` and I have this problem.

I want to add some labels below the `UITextField` and the problem is that when I compute the position of the label it does't take the position based on the device size but based on the `storyboard` size.

To be more spesific my code is

```
private func setUpBottomRightLabel(){
    let height:CGFloat = self.layer.frame.height / 2
    let lBottomRight = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height + 2, width: self.frame.width * 0.6, height: height))
    lBottomRight.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 4)
    lBottomRight.text = "\(self.text?.count ?? 0)/\(self.maxNumber)"
    lBottomRight.textAlignment = .right
    lBottomRight.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.superview!.addSubview(lBottomRight)
    self.updateConstraints()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

And the problem is that when this function is being called from `awakeFromNib()` or `init()` the textfield `self.frame.width = 359` but when the ViewControllers `function ViewDidAppear` is being called the `CustomTextField.frame.width is 304.0`.

Witch delegate method should I call from `CustomTextField` file to call the methods that add the labels to the Textfield that will that will take the size based on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CustomTextField`, `override` the `layoutSubviews` as below to get the correct `frame` and then add the bottom label

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        print("\(self.frame)")
    }
}
```